# Running a Python job remotely with ssh---how can I log out?

Tags: python, bash, ssh, sh

I am running a Python script `filename.py` via ssh. Once I'm logged into the remote machine, I run:

```
python filename.py &
```

However, when I close out of the terminal, it appears the python stops running. Why is this? I thought an ampersand `&` at the end of a statement meant the program kept running?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `nohup`:

```
nohup python filename.py &
```

`nohup [command] &` will run the job in the background and return you back to the shell.

Comment: Additional info, [nohup is a POSIX command to ignore the HUP (hangup) signal. The HUP signal is, by convention, the way a terminal warns dependent processes of logout.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

Comment: I get the following response after running this command:
`$ nohup: ignoring input and appending output to nohup.out`

Comment: The output from `nohup`, by default, gets written to a file called `nohup.out`. If you want to watch it run, you can `tail -f nohup.out`.

Comment: @AlexWoolford Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I am not so far into python in shell, but you can use screen in ssh related enviroments

For example:

```
sudo apt-get install screen

screen -m
```

This will create virual tty (pty)

Then run your program

```
python prog.py &
```

Hope it will work fine for you, have a nice day!