# Exiting a bash shell after script backgrounds a task

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following script that I run from a bash shell. After I execute it and I observe the `********* Exiting ***********` statement I wish to quit the bash shell but have the backgrounded `java` process continue. However, when I do type `exit` at my bash prompt it simply echo's back `exit` but then just sits there.

**Question:** is there a way for me to background a task from within a script such that I can exit the shell and have the task continue?

```
#!/bin/sh
pid=$(cat /tmp/myapp.pid)
if [ "$(ps -o comm= -p "$pid")" = "java" ]; then
  echo "Killing the previous myapp process"
  kill $pid
else echo "Could not find a previously running myapp process"
fi
cd ~/deploy
echo "Launching myapp"
java -Dconfig.file=./myapp-1.conf -jar myapp.jar & echo "$!" > /tmp/myapp.pid
sleep 5
echo "********* Exiting ***********"
```

Comment: See: [Linux: Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](http://stackoverflow.com/q/285015/3776858)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
#!/bin/sh
...
nohup [command] &
exit 0
```