# Run python constantly on the Google cloud platform

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

So currently I'm trying to host a little bot I made in Python. It's meant to be running 24/7 so I tried Google cloud platform. I have a Ubuntu dist installed on a small scale VM server and I can run the bot perfectly. However when I exit out of my ssh session the python stops running. I've tried searching for solutions but I've found nothing.

So, how do I keep running python 24/7 on my Ubuntu VM?

Comment: Start with [tmux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tmux), [screen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Screen) and all those tools.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linux: Prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/linux-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-ssh-client)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical solution for this would be either [`tmux`](https://hackernoon.com/a-gentle-introduction-to-tmux-8d784c404340?gi=d0b4ca6c999b) or [`screen`](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_screen). I prefer `tmux`, so I'll give instructions for that.

Start by installing `tmux`

```
sudo apt-get install tmux
```

Then start a session:

```
tmux new -s mybot
```

Then start your bot with whatever command you would normally use. Detach from the screen with `Ctrl-a Ctr-d`. You can now exit your ssh session and the bot will still be running.

To reattach to the session (to shut down the bot or whatever), just run:

```
tmux attach -t mybot
```