# Queue processing in background with Laravel 5.6 stops when terminal is closed

Tags: linux, laravel, queue, jobs, nohup

I used the following commands to set my queue process in execution forever even after I close the server terminal. But it stops as soon as I close the terminal. Please help me with this. How to put it always running in the background.
You can see I used all nohup commands but no luck.

```
1) nohup php artisan queue:work --tries=1 </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 &
2) nohup php artisan queue:work --tries=1 >/dev/null 2>&1 &
3) nohup php artisan queue:work --daemon > /dev/null 2>&1 &
4) nohup php artisan queue:work > /dev/null 2>&1 &
5) nohup php artisan queue:work --tries=1
6) nohup php artisan queue:listen >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

**Note: I am not having `root` access of the server. I am using user created from WHM. IDK if that is the problem.**

Comment: better to run it from a `crontab` or create a `systemd` thingy?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Linux, how to prevent a background process from being stopped after closing SSH client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285015/in-linux-how-to-prevent-a-background-process-from-being-stopped-after-closing-s)

Comment: when you're having trouble, you don't want to discard all the information that might appear on `std-out` and `std-err`. I recommend redirecting that output to tmp files and see if there is any helpful evidence. What you have seems like it should work, (Except that your line 5 is not backgrounded, (typo?)). Good luck.

Comment: @frakman1 it is not helpful as you can see I am already using nohup to solve the issue.

Comment: @shellter, I did not understand your concern for line #5.

Comment: Is it missing the `&` at the end, or is that deliberate? As is, that job will have to complete before it goes on to line 6. Good luck.

Comment: Also, let us know (by editing your Q), are you using `ssh`, `putty` (which mode), or something else. Also, yes agree that you are already using `nohup`, but there are a lot of other good solutions in that answer. Good luck.

Comment: You might also try to see if it something special about `php artisan` and run a very simple `nohup` test, maybe `nohup sleep 360 &`, then copy/paste the returned PID, restart your terminal is `ps -ef | grep $PIDyouCaptured`. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `CPanel` -> `Cron Jobs` page

And create a cron job by adding a command like this:

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

**Don't forget to change /path-to-your-project as your project folder**

It will run laravel scheduled commands.

And put this to `schedule`  method in  `app/Console/Kernel.php` file.

```
$schedule->command('queue:work --stop-when-empty')->everyMinute()->withoutOverlapping();
```

Comment: çok sağlıklı görünmüyor. `--once` desen anlarım.. Ama yukarıdaki komut her dakika yeni bir deaoman başlatacak. 1 saatte 60 instance 24 saatte bir boot edilen server düşün adam gün sonunda makinesinde 1440 instance çalıştıracak..

Comment: @TeomanTıngır  haklısın öyle bir problem var ona dikkat etmemişim.  Ama --once  kuyruktan 1 job işleyip kapanıyor. Bahsettiğin  problem için --stop-when-empty  seçeneğini ekleyerek yanıtı güncelliyorum.

Comment: cron ile çok sağlıklı değil açıkçası queue işlemlerini başlatmak. doğrudan servis yazıp boot anında artisan komutu çalıştırmak daha sağlıklı. wanted by mult user target der geçersin. ama işte hostinglerde sıkıntı :))

Answer (score 0):

Afraid that is not possible, when you stop the command or close your connection the process will stop.

From the Laravel documentation

> To keep the queue:work process running permanently in the background,
>   you should use a process monitor such as Supervisor to ensure that the
>   queue worker does not stop running.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queues#supervisor-configuration

Comment: That should work, but it's a quick fix and not a good long term solution. The process could stop because of an error or when the server is rebooted etc.